# How to get GRUB back after overwrite?

Tags: linux, grub2, boot-loader

I have an internal hard drive with the Linux distro I use daily.
Today, I wanted to test another distro, I installed it on a USB flash drive, but GRUB was installed on my internal hard drive.

Why on hell would GRUB go on my hard drive, and how can I recover my previous GRUB menu?

(My daily distro is Fedora with encrypted LVM).

Comment: boot with a live cd, if you are using grub2 http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2

Answer (score 1):

As c4f4t0r said, boot with a live CD. You can then run `grub-install /dev/sda` or whatever drive you need. You may need to bind mount `/proc`, `/boot`, `/dev` and `/sys` and the chroot into your mounted linux installation first.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you still have a grub installed, just without the menu. You can use its command line to boot your existing distro. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>, etc. to get into the grub menu. Then press `c` for the command line.

Then you can just run the lines that would normally boot your machine (they're in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` normally). Something like:

```
grub> linux (hd0,0)/vmlinuz-3.12-1-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/Zia-root ro verbose
grub> initrd (hd0,0)/initrd.img-3.12-1-amd64
grub> boot
```

Your may need an insmod or two (possibilities include at least `ext2`, `part_msdos`, and `gzio`). Your normal grub.cfg will probably do searches by fs UUID, which is more robust, but you can just give disk numbers as above.

Once you have your machine booted, use your distro's normal way of installing grub (e.g., `grub-install`)